# Approximating states of the enveloping von Neumann Algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, weak-convergence, von-neumann-algebras, dual-spaces

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-Algebra and $A''$ its enveloping von Neumann Algebra.
Is the state space $S(A)$ of $A$ weak*-dense in the state space of $S(A'')$? I Know that every state on $A$ extends as a vector-state to a normal state on $A''$ and that $A$ is weak*-dense in $A^{**}\cong A''$. But I don't seem to get how you can approximate a state in $S(A'')$ by an state in $S(A)$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a subtlety. You can prove that you can approximate states of $A^{**}$ by those of $A$ but the proof is not constructive,  it does not give you a way to "construct" an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can reformulated as asking whether the positive part of the unit ball of $A^{\ast \ast}$ can be approximated (in the $\sigma(A^{\ast \ast \ast}, A^{\ast})$-topology) by elements in the positive part of $A^{\ast \ast}$.

If you remove the positivity assumption this is usually called [Goldstine theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem) and holds true for every Banach space, not just duals of $C^\ast$-algebras. You can try to extend the proof to positive functional, it uses a Hahn-Banach separation argument, see this [notes](https://web.archive.org/web/20180920180340/https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~lwmarcou/Preprints/LinearAnalysis.pdf)[p97] therefore it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Sadly, the link to the notes does not work for me. I got it to work! Thanks!

Comment: I tried proving it along the lines of the notes but since the set of positive linear functionals with norm less or equal to1 is not balanced the proof does not hold. Is there a way to get around this?